# Kentico API to update settings doesn't reflect in CMS

Tags: c#, .net, kentico, kentico-api

I'm trying to programmatically update the WIF thumbprint value in Kentico. I've developed a small app that does the following:

**Get's the value**
`string thumprintValue = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue("CMSWIFTrustedCertificateThumbprint");`

**Set's the new value**
`SettingsKeyInfoProvider.SetGlobalValue("CMSWIFTrustedCertificateThumbprint", newThumbprintValue);`

I can see the value being updated in the database. The app returns the new value as well.

The problem is that when I login to Kentico CMS (I'm using Kentico 9.0.42 BTW) and check the value in the portal, it still shows the old value.

I checked that the app and the Kentico CMS app are both connecting to the same database. What else could it be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely a cached value you're seeing in the database.  Clear the cache in the System app and try viewing the settings again.

Comment: Thanks and apologies for the delayed response. Manually clearing the system cache worked. Additionally, I tried using `CacheHelper.ClearCache();`  after setting the value hoping I can programmatically clear cache rather than from the UI but this didn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: This also works if you've updated the settings via SQL